# Grain-128 Cipher sample input and output

Tags: c, cryptography, stream-cipher

I downloaded grain 128 program code from the ecrypt website http://www.ecrypt.eu.org/stream/grainp3.html for carrying out my research on grain-128. I couldn't setup the estream software setup framework and run original grain 128.So I modified the same C program to work independently but unfortunately I don't have any sample input output pairs(key, IV, output keystream) for testing the code. Can somebody help me?

Comment: Did you check the test vectors, verified or not, in *any* of the plethora of documents at the site you linked in your question?

Comment: I checked. In the grain-128 zipped folder, there is a file named 'test vectors.c' where key and iv are given but corresponding keystream bits are not given.